# Make a submit button send email with details in HTML

Tags: html, forms, email

I have a form in HTML with a submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="subscribe-submit" onclick="return foo()">Subscribe</button>
```

I would like it to have the details written on the form to be sent to my personal email address.

I have searched on Stack Overflow, Google, Bing and Yahoo but I couldn't find the answer

Comment: Some how, the html tags do not appear, except when one click the "edit" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with pure HTML. However, with a little PHP you can get your form ready to go.

Here's an example of a form handler PHP code in a separate file called form_handler.php:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['comment'];

$mail_to = 'yourPersonalEmail@email.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the feedback.');
        window.location = 'form.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again or contact at myPersonalEmail@email.com');
        window.location = 'form.html';
    </script>
<?php
}

?>
```

And here's the HTML form in a file called form.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="form_handler.php" method="POST">
       <label class="name">Name</label>
       <br>
       <input name="name" type="text" required="required">
       <br>
       <label class="email">E-Mail</label>
       <br>
       <input name="email" type="email" required="required">
       <br>
       <label class="comment">Comment</label>
       <br>
       <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
       <br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" align="center">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest you learn a little bit about PHP and form handing. You might need to change the fields but I think you'll get the idea.